How to resolve glibc errors in conda enviroment installation?
I am a non root user in a Linux based cluster. It doesn't have docker nor I have privileges to install it. The base environment have GLIBC version 2.17. I am trying to install packages (like faiss-gpu, ollama etc.) which have higher GLIBC requirements. I don't want to break the system by upgrading base's GLIBC. I am confused that how should I handle this problem.
Upon searching I found multiple posts which to best of my knowledge indicated to install GLIBC and its dependencies in separate path and then configure before building or using patchelf to newer paths. I was unable to understand most of the information, but tried installing GLIBC in a separate conda environment using conda install conda-forge::libgcc-ng conda-forge::libstdcxx-ng vikky34v::glibc and changing environment variable using export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(conda info --base)/envs/your_env/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH, when I verify it using strings $(conda info --base)/envs/glibc/lib/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC" it shows 'GLIBC 2.33' . Despite this still when I try to install package they give GLIBC error (like

Package pyparsing conflicts for:
wheel -> packaging[version='>=20.2'] -> pyparsing[version='<3,>=2.0.2|>=2.0.2,!=3.0.5|>=2.0.2,<3|>=2.0.2']
pytorch::faiss-gpu -> packaging -> pyparsing[version='<3,>=2.0.2|>=2.0.2,!=3.0.5|>=2.0.2,<3|>=2.0.2']The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:
feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0
feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0
pytorch::faiss-gpu -> __glibc[version='>=2.17,<3.0.a0']
Your installed version is: 2.17

For Linux version and distribution, I ran cat /proc/version command and it gives

Linux version 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
(mockbuild@x86-040.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.8.5
20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Oct 4 20:48:51 UTC 2018

If some one can simple down my options and how can I or should have proceeded for troubleshooting it will be of great help.

Please edit your question to add which Linux distribution and version.

@JohnMahowald Done, please check if anything else required.
